# JavaFX ListView Multiple Selection

Tags: listview, javafx

I want to select multiple items from ListView. It would react on mouse click. I tried with this:

```
selectedLogsList.addAll(logsListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```

but it was giving me duplicates.
So I tried this:

```
logsListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, 
                String old_val, String new_val) {
                    if(selectedLogsList.contains(new_val)) {
                        selectedLogsList.remove(new_val);
                    } else {
                        selectedLogsList.add(new_val);
                    }
        }
    });
```

I would also like that, if cell is selected, it should be marked as such (different background color)
Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? do you want to know all items selected? You can make your ListView multi-selectable by :      listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

Comment: That simple :D It worked regarding multiple selection with CTRL. But it still makes duplicates. If I click multiple times on same cell, it adds it every time. Instead, I want it to remove it second time I click.

Comment: If you copy the code from my answer below it does exactly what you want. If you press CTRL you can add several items and in the setOnMouseClicked() method you will get all selected items. If you deselect an item (still pressing CTRL) it will again call the setOnMouseClicked()-method, but this time the item will not be in the list.

Comment: I got it now. I was trying similar thing, but seems I was failing somewhere. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you just want to know which items are selected have a look at my example. Have a look at the setOnMouseClicked() method..

```
    package application;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
    import javafx.event.Event;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
    import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class Main extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            try {
                Pane  root = new Pane();
                Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
                scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

                ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();

                ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();





                listView.setItems(list);

                list.add("item1");
                list.add("item2");
                list.add("item3");

                listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);


                listView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(Event event) {
                        ObservableList<String> selectedItems =  listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

                        for(String s : selectedItems){
                            System.out.println("selected item " + s);
                        }

                    }

                });


                list.add("item4");  

                root.getChildren().add(listView);

                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if the user uses the keyboard to select items. You should register a listener with `list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` instead of using a mouse listener.