# How to set text and color of multiple ListView items when clicked

Tags: javafx

I know there are many related questions about this but maybe I'm missing something because I can't get the behavior I'm expecting, to work.

```
@FXML
private ListView<String> guiList;

void performAction(Actions action) {
    try {
        Task<String> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            public String call() {
                String mySelection = Context.getInstance().getSelected();
                ArrayList<String> selectedList = Context.getInstance().getItemsClicked();
                if (selectedList == null) {
                    selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                selectedList.add(mySelection);
                Context.getInstance().setItemsClicked(selectedList);
                guiList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                        ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if(item != null && item.matches(mySelection)) {
                                    setText(mySelection + " [" + action + "]");
                                    setFont(Font.font(Font.getDefault().getFamily(), FontWeight.BOLD, Font.getDefault().getSize()));
                                    setStyle("-fx-text-fill: green;");
                                } else {
                                    setText(item);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        return cell;
                    }
                });
                return "";
            }
        };
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

When I click in an item of **guiList**, the text is changed, gets bold and shows in green color but I don't understand why I need the **else** statement. If I don't use it, all the other items of the list disappear.

I ask this because I want to change **ALL** of the items I click and in the current behavior, the changes are only made in the last one clicked.

Comment: When you override the updateItem, it will be your duty to set the text in the cell. As per your code, if the text not matches, and if you dont set the text in the else part, then there will not be any text in the cells.

Comment: If you don't have the `else` clause, you don't set the text for items that don't match your selection, so nothing is displayed. The other part of your question can't be answered without a [mre]; it's not really clear at all what your code has to do with selecting items in the list.

Comment: I edited my code to add more information that was missing. When I click an item, I add the item information (the text) to an array so that at any given time, I have a list of items I clicked. So, when I click something and set a new text or color, the next time I click another, I don't want to change the last one(s).

Comment: @James_D so it's not possible to just change one of the items? I always have to do something in all of them?

Comment: `updateItem()` will be called when needed (when the list view reuses a cell or detects a change in the state of a cell). You have to cover all possibilities in that method. It’s called at least once for each cell and is the only place the text can be set. So if you don’t set the text for a cell then the text is never set. You also need to set the style and font in your `else` clause, because if a cell displaying an item that matches your `if` condition is reused for an item that doesn’t match that condition, the font and style will be wrong. Again, please post a [mre].

Comment: the one thingy to fully understand about cells: they are __re-used__ (might be an empty row!) and this re-use is __not__ under the control of application code. As a consequence, every implementation must re/set all state it touches in both of the if/else blocks. In your shoes I would do some research, starting with the api doc of Cell/updateItem - which unfortunately isn't top-notch ;) - there are many QAs here around correct implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is on approach. Use an object that has a `Boolean` variable to keeps up with if the item has been selected.

---

### KeyCode 1

```
lvMain.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(((ov, t, t1) - > {
    if (t1 != null) {
        t1.setSelected(true);
    }
}));
```

---

**Key Code 2**

```
lvMain.setCellFactory(lv - > new ListCell < MyItem > () {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(MyItem item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.getText());
            if (item.isSelected()) {
                setTextFill(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

**Main**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<MyItem> lvMain = new ListView();//Create ListView  
        lvMain.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);//Change ListView selection mode to multiple
        ObservableList<MyItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new MyItem("Julia"), new MyItem("Ian"), new MyItem("Sue"), new MyItem("Matthew"), new MyItem("Hannah"));//ObseravableList that will be used to set the ListView
        lvMain.setItems(items);//Set the ListView's items
        lvMain.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<MyItem>()
        {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(MyItem item, boolean empty)
            {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
                else {
                    setText(item.getText());
                    if(item.isSelected())
                    {
                        setTextFill(Color.RED);
                    }                    
                }
            }
        });
        lvMain.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(((ov, t, t1) -> {
            if(t1 != null)
            {
                t1.setSelected(true);
            }
        }));        


        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(lvMain);


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

---

**MyItem**

```
/**
 *
 * @author Sed
 */
public class MyItem {
    private String text;
    private boolean selected;

    public MyItem(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.selected = false;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.selected = isSelected;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }    
}
```

---

**Output**

[image]

---

I think a better solution would be to use the `ListView's` built in [multiple selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158394/javafx-listview-multiple-selection) or have your cells have a `ToggleButton`. When the `ToggleButton` is on, change the color of the text. When it is off, change the color back to it's original state.

Comment: Thanks @SedJ601. I will accept your answer. But there is no multiselection in my case. I solved my issue after understanding that I always have to set EVERY item in the list.